# Wordpress filter products by price using numeric comparison

Tags: php, wordpress, filter, filtering

With pre_get_posts I extend the query with filters.
I'm now trying to make a custom price filter, because i can't use the original filter

De code i'm using:

```
$minprice = 0;
$maxprice = 0;
if ( isset( $_GET['min_price'] ) && $_GET['min_price'] > 0 ) $minprice = $_GET['min_price'];
if ( isset( $_GET['max_price'] ) && $_GET['max_price'] > 0 ) $maxprice = $_GET['max_price'];

if ( $minprice > 0 || $maxprice > 0 ) {
    $compare = '=';
    $metavalue = '';
    if ( $minprice > 0 && $maxprice > 0 ) { $compare = 'between'; $metavalue = array( $minprice, $maxprice ); }
    if ( $minprice > 0 && $maxprice <= 0 ) { $compare = '>='; $metavalue = $minprice; }
    if ( $maxprice > 0 && $minprice <= 0 ) { $compare = '<='; $metavalue = $maxprice; }

    $query->set( 'meta_key', 'price' );
    $query->set( 'meta_value', $metavalue );
    $query->set( 'meta_compare', $compare );
}
```

The problem is that if i fill in 10 for min_price i also get 2 euro products.
I know WP is comparing the values as string.
How can I make it numeric?

EDIT:

I made some progress by adding:
`$query->set( 'meta_type', 'decimal' );`

But when i fill in 10 as minprice and 20 as maxprice I also get results like 9,86 and 20,30.

When i fill in 10.50 as minprice and 20 as maxprice, everything before 10,50 is gone as it shoot, but 20,30 is still there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fonud the solution.

It is an (old) mysql bug:
https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=61691

I have changed it to:

`$query->set( 'meta_type', 'DECIMAL(20,2)' );`